# Replacing colum with values from lookup table in R

Tags: r, merge, lookup-tables

I need to replace the values of a column `model` in `ddata`:

```
> unique(ddata$model)
[1] "GT-I9001"    "iPhone5,2"    "iPhone3,1"                        
[4] "iPhone4,1"   "GT-I9300"     "Nexus 4"                         
[7] "iPhone2,1"   "VS840 4G"     "HTC One X+"  
...
```

with those from a lookup table, which I imported as

```
> devices
...
15 iPhone1,1         iPhone 2G,
16 iPhone1,2         iPhone 3G,
17 iPhone2,1         iPhone 3GS,
18 iPhone3,1         iPhone 4,
19 iPhone3,2         iPhone 4,
20 iPhone3,3         iPhone 4,
21 iPhone4,1         iPhone 4S,
22 iPhone5,1         iPhone 5,
23 iPhone5,2         iPhone 5,
...
```

So that, for example, `iPhone4,1` becomes `iPhone4S`. If a key is not present in the lookup table, I want to keep the original value of `ddata$model`, so for example the original `Nexus 4` remains `Nexus 4`.

I tried with `merge`, but I don't know how to address the case where a key is missing:

```
ddata2 = merge(ddata,devices,by="model", all.x=T)
```

The problem being that `ddata2` has **N/A** for those values that don't have an entry in `devices`.

Comment: Same question but with a poorer title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324851/replace-multible-data-codes-in-a-datafram-with-names/17325215#17325215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `merge` like above, then follow with:

```
ddata2 <- within( ddata2, model[ is.na(model2) ] <- model[ is.na(model2) ] )
```

Assuming that the 2nd column in devices is called model2.

Comment: I'm going to accept this one as it doesn't require the extra `qdap` package.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using [qdap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdap/):

```
## key <- readLines(n=9)
## iPhone1,1         iPhone 2G,
## iPhone1,2         iPhone 3G,
## iPhone2,1         iPhone 3GS,
## iPhone3,1         iPhone 4,
## iPhone3,2         iPhone 4,
## iPhone3,3         iPhone 4,
## iPhone4,1         iPhone 4S,
## iPhone5,1         iPhone 5,
## iPhone5,2         iPhone 5,
## 
## library(qdap)
## key <- colSplit(key, "         ")
## 
## ddata <- data.frame(model = c("GT-I9001",    "iPhone5,2",    "iPhone3,1",                        
##     "iPhone4,1",   "GT-I9300",     "Nexus 4",                         
##     "iPhone2,1",   "VS840 4G",     "HTC One X+"))

library(qdap)

ddata$model <- as.character(ddata$model)

ddata$model <- lookup(ddata$model, key, missing =NULL) ## OR
ddata$model <- ddata$model %l+% key
```

Please note that your data was difficult to read in.  Please use `dput` for odd data sets.  Also I believe a similar question was asked recently but can't find it.